# How to disable F1 with focus on a menuitem?

Tags: delphi, menuitem, popupmenu

How to disable the <kbd>F1</kbd> key in Delphi with the focus on a menu item in a popup menu?

When opening a popup menu with a focus on any item, if the <kbd>F1</kbd> button is pressed, an error occurs:

> No contextual help installed

How to block an F1 key with the focus on an item in the popup menu?  I tried as below, but it didn't work.

```pascal
procedure TForm1.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if Key = VK_F1 then Key := 0;
end;
```

Sorted out [How to apply a keyboardhook on F1 within the application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55452624/)

Comment: Drop a `TApplicationEvents` on your main form and write an `OnHelp` handler: `function TForm1.ApplicationEvents1Help(Command: Word; Data: NativeInt;
  var CallHelp: Boolean): Boolean;
begin
  CallHelp := False;
end;`